# MSTest can't discover inherited TestMethod in a child Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, mstest

I'm using Visual Studio 2015,
My probleme is that MSTest cannot discover the TestMethods that are already defined in base class, when I click "Run Tests" in vs, only the test that are defined in child class are executed.

exemple

```
[TestClass]
public class A 
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void Test1(){....}
}

[TestClass]
public class B : A
{
  [TestMethod]
  // MsTest only discover this method to execute!
  public void Test2(){....}
}
```

I want both method to get executed when I click "Run Tests" when I'm in class B, how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: You may need to be more specific about the issue you're seeing (perhaps including screenshots), a sample test project where I've pasted the entirety of your code in (and removed the `….` so it'll compile) results in Test Explorer showing A > Test 1 and B > Test 1, Test 2 and running tests for `B` runs both `Test1` and `Test2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could mark it as virtual and then override it and re-supply the `TestMethod` attribute on the override and have the method call through to the base implementation.

```
[TestClass]
public class A 
{
  [TestMethod]
  public virtual void Test1(){....}
}

[TestClass]
public class B : A
{
  [TestMethod]
  public override void Test1()
  {
    base.Test1();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void Test2(){....}
}
```